# ListView.scrollTo works slow with huge number of items

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-2

The scrollTo method in the code below works really slow. Is there any way to speed up it or may be some alternative variant? I need to display almost 100000 items in the application. Probably there are some alternative components. Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        Button button = new Button("goto");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                int i = 99998;
                System.out.println("before scroll");
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                listView.scrollTo(i);
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                System.out.println(elapsedTime);
                listView.getFocusModel().focus(i);
            }
        });
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            items.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(items));
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(button);
        vbox.getChildren().add(listView);
        pane.getChildren().add(vbox);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a design problem, requiring a design solution.  Perhaps you could create a collapsible list with a search box, where the list doesn't populate until the user types something in the search box that yields 1000 items or less.  If the items have some sort of categorization that the user can select, you can filter the list on that.  Alternatively, you could write your own listview with an indexing capability, or subclass the existing one.

Comment: Do you really want a listview with 100.000 items? This will be extremely hard to use it for anything, I suggest you look into some paging option.

Comment: I strongly agree with the previous comments; this is simply a really poor design and you should consider using a Pagination or some other way to improve the user experience anyway. However: the performance issue is greatly improved in JavaFX 8; in JavaFX 2.2 this takes about 2.2 seconds to scroll on my system, in JavaFX 8 it takes 2 milliseconds.

Comment: Unfortunatly, It is the customer requirement: to display such a big plain list, and I am not able to change his mind